# Vectorised implementation of Normal Distribution

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to implement a vectorised implementation of the gaussian distribution without using any numpy functions.

Just to be clear I'd like to achieve the same result as below without the forloop.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    y[i] = normpdf(y[i], 0, .1)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

def normpdf(x, mean, sd):
    var = float(sd)**2
    denom = (2*math.pi*var)**.5
    num = math.exp(-(float(x)-float(mean))**2/(2*var))
    return num/denom
```

Comment: Could you change your code so that normpdf is defined before it is called in the for loop ?

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to do this "without using any numpy functions"? You're already using `np.linspace`, and you've said that you want a vectorized solution, which usually means exploiting numpy array methods. Were you aware of [`scipy.stats.norm.pdf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)?

Comment: That's how iv'e defined it in my Notebook, still won't work vectorised.@ ali_m there's no functional reason, it's part of an exercise to vectorise an ML algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `math.exp`, `np.exp` can operate (pointwise) directly on arrays. So replacing normpdf by:

```
def normpdf(x, mean, sd):
    var = float(sd)**2
    denom = (2*math.pi*var)**.5
    num = np.exp(-( x - mean)**2/(2*var))
    return num/denom
```

You can directly call normpdf on x without the loop.

I don't really understand how you want to benefit from numpy vectorization without using numpy functions.

Comment: Gives me this error: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: @CharlesLucienFried I removed your unnecessary float() and now it works.

Comment: @CharlesLucienFried If this works, consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the validation sign next to the voting arrows